# Ajax call completes before all node callbacks are executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, callback

I am trying to make a ajax post call to a node server and then redirect user once the call is completed. Here is my jquery function for making the post ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/myUrl', 
  type: 'POST',
  data: { myParam: myParam,fileName: finalName},
  success: function(data, status){
    alert('Ajax call completed!');
    customFunction(status);

  }, 
  error: function(xOptions, textStatus){
    alert('Error occured!: '+textStatus);
  }
});
```

Now, at the server end, I am handling this request as:

```
var modCust = require('./custom-module')

app.post('/myUrl',function(req,res){
  var myParam = req.body.myParam;
  var fileName = req.body.fileName;

  var cli = modCust.parseExcel(fileName,myParam);
  res.send(cli);
});
```

and this custom-module is using nested callbacks to perform multiple db functions as:

```
//#custom-module.js

executeQuery = function(strSQL, operationType, tableName, cb,myParam) {
    var request = new sql.Request(connection);
    request.query(strSQL,function(err, recordset) {
        if(err){
            console.error('ERROR in '+operationType+' ON '+tableName+': '+err);
        }
        console.info(operationType+' ON '+tableName+' successful!');
        if(cb){
            cb(myParam);
        }

        return recordset;
    });
};

parseFile: function(filePath, myParam){
  var strSQL = "<sample query>";
  executeQuery(strSQL,'<QueryType>','<table_name>',processDB1,myParam);
},

processDB1: function(myParam){
  var strSQL = "<sample query>";
  executeQuery(strSQL,'<QueryType>','<table_name>',processDB2,myParam);
},

processDB2: function(myParam){
  var strSQL = "<sample query>";
  executeQuery(strSQL,'<QueryType>','<table_name>',processDB3,myParam);
},

processDB3: function(myParam){
  var strSQL = "<sample query>";
  executeQuery(strSQL,'<QueryType>','<table_name>');
},
```

But the issue is, the alert call is executed even before all the callbacks are completed till processDB3(). Can I make the alert pop-up only after the last callback is completed from node?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into promises in javascript. The function parseExcel should return promise so that you can do as follow:

```
modCust.parseExcel(fileName,myParam).then(function(resultFromParseExcelFunction) {
    res.send(resultFromParseExcelFunction)
})
```

Check out [node package q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) to achieve promises in easy way.